# CDK Stack Export Resource not Found

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm trying to import values generated and exported from a cdk stack that deploys into eu-west-1 into a stack that needs to be deployed into af-south-1 but I keep getting the error that the export name does not exist:

EU

```js
new CfnOutput(this, 'userPoolArn', {
value: this.userPoolPattern.userPoolArn,})
```

AF

```js
const userPoolArn = cdk.Fn.importValue('EuWest1Infrastructure:userPoolArn');
```

Error:
`AfSouth1Infrastructure |  0/44 | 20:10:55 | ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            | AfSouth1Infrastructure No export named EuWest1Infrastructure:userPoolArn found. Rollback requested by user.`

I've tried using the value that gets outputted in the console but it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a cross-region cross-stack reference, set the [`crossRegionReferences` Stack prop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Stack.html#crossregionreferences) to `true` and simply pass the reference around. Here is an [example from the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#accessing-resources-in-a-different-stack-and-region):

```
const stack1 = new Stack(app, 'Stack1', {
  env: {
    region: 'us-east-1',
  },
  crossRegionReferences: true,
});
const cert = new acm.Certificate(stack1, 'Cert', {
  domainName: '*.example.com',
  validation: acm.CertificateValidation.fromDns(route53.PublicHostedZone.fromHostedZoneId(stack1, 'Zone', 'Z0329774B51CGXTDQV3X')),
});

const stack2 = new Stack(app, 'Stack2', {
  env: {
    region: 'us-east-2',
  },
  crossRegionReferences: true,
});
new cloudfront.Distribution(stack2, 'Distribution', {
  defaultBehavior: {
    origin: new origins.HttpOrigin('example.com'),
  },
  domainNames: ['dev.example.com'],
  certificate: cert,
});
```

Here, the `cert` construct is simply passed around and the necessary cross-region references are created automatically. You can do the same with your UserPool.

This feature is experimental as of CDK 2.114.1

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**: A `CfnOutput` doesn't create a [cross-stack reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html) unless you set the `exportName` prop:

```js
new CfnOutput(this, 'userPoolArn', {
value: this.userPoolPattern.userPoolArn,
exportName: 'UserPoolCrossStackRef', // <--
})
```

Within a single region you could then consume the value into another stack using `cdk.Fn.importValue("UserPoolCrossStackRef")`.

**Problem 2:** Cross-stack references don't work across regions:

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html): You can't create cross-stack references across regions. You can use the intrinsic function Fn::ImportValue to import only values that have been exported within the same region.